# How to safely reduce ubuntu-vg (LVM) to increase /boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, lvm

I keep having issues with the size of my /boot for updates (see also [my post history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428702/not-enough-space-on-boot-but-no-kernels-left-to-remove)) and so I am looking into how to increase the size of /boot from ~500MB to ~1GB. However, after booting into gparted live and trying to resize the disk, I've been running into issues with ubuntu-vg taking up all of the rest of the space, not being able to resize that, and not finding a thorough guide on how to safely do this. (Why do I have an ubuntu-vg? I read [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) and dont quite understand).

The best looking guide I've found is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/951283/1148174) but I am a bit lost on the safest way to accomplish step 1, reduce the PV. Almost every guide is only about increasing, and [this guide](https://quickpacket.com/billing/knowledgebase/4/How-to-resize-volumes-with-LVM.html) paints a lot of caution into the process, but is this the best way?

Can I simply remove it, as explored in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228136/how-to-remove-all-lvs-vgs-and-partitions-on-all-drives-before-installing-12-04)?

And as I look at the code output below, whats with the reference to snap/firefox for the 100GB section?

Thanks for helping me not nuke my system.

Here's what lsblk output looks like:

```
lsblk 
sdd              8:48   0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sdd1           8:49   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sdd2           8:50   0   488M  0 part  /boot
└─sdd3           8:51   0 110.8G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt 253:0    0 110.8G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root
    │          253:1    0 102.8G  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
    │                                     /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
           253:2    0     8G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1
           253:3    0     8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

System info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ uname -r
5.15.0-48-generic

$ ls -l /boot
total 345163
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    261841 Aug 10 00:49 config-5.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    261861 Aug 26 02:12 config-5.15.0-48-generic
drwx------ 3 root root      4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root      1024 Sep 22 10:28 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 Sep 22 10:28 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157682858 Sep 11 11:30 initrd.img-5.15.0-47-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 157726714 Sep 22 10:28 initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        28 Sep 21 19:04 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.15.0-47-generic
drwx------ 2 root root     12288 Sep  1  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    182800 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184476 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184980 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root   6245466 Aug 10 00:49 System.map-5.15.0-47-generic
-rw------- 1 root root   6245527 Aug 26 02:12 System.map-5.15.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Sep 21 19:04 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11530816 Aug 11 00:44 vmlinuz-5.15.0-47-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11526304 Aug 26 06:13 vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        25 Sep 21 19:04 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-47-generic
```

Comment: You have Ubuntu-vg because you selected encryption in the advanced installation option.

Comment: Anytime you use encryption, you must have extremely good backup procedures. And all users must refresh backup before making any system changes. but 500MB for /boot should be plenty. What is taking all the space. You normally would have two kernels & related files. I am using Jammy and have two kernels using about 288MB.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is running?

Comment: @oldfred see updates above - For two kernels I'm above 300MB, and I hit a 'not enough free space on boot' error every time I use software updater. I'm using COMPRESS=xy in initramfs as suggested by my previous problem (link added above for that)